# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found while deploying on remote Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a spring boot application with the main class like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEmailTools
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class SimApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SimApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonViewSupportFactoryBean views() {
        return new JsonViewSupportFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

I also have controller for / like this

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Running locally it displays the `login` page. But when I generate war file and deploy it on Tomcat remote server, it always gives me this error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.19
```

Url for localhost is `http://localhost:8080/` this redirects me to Login. Now after deploying to Tomcat on a remote server, whenever I hit `http://remoteurl:8080/artifact-id/` it sends me to the error page.
What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you try adding `@ResponseBody` on `login()` method

Comment: Still the same error, does this might be due to wrong base url?

Comment: is artifact-id is same as the base name of the WAR file?

Comment: by base name you mean the file name of the WAR file?

Comment: nothing wrong with application i guess.. is other apps to http://remoteurl:8080/ accessible? meaning other apps inside webapps of remote tomcat.

Comment: yes, tomcat managers are accessible but the urls after my articact-id are not